# How can i override double underscore function in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, class, exception, helper

As i said before how can i override double underscore function ?

**I dont want to use helper folder.**

I want to create a new class and in this class i want to override this __ function. And i want to call this function from everywhere with simply __("lorem").

```
<?php
namespace App\Classes;

use bla bla;

class Translater{

      //Some transactions

}
```

After close my classes curly brackets i write my own __ function.

```
function __($text){

static $translaterClass = null;
if($translaterClass == null) $translaterClass = new Translater();

return $translaterClass->translate($text);
}
```

I tried to add app.php's aliases

```
'Lang' => App\Classes\Translater::class,
```

I also tried app.php's providers

```
App\Classes\Translater::class,
```

After this steps i call this function without and with use App\Classes\Translater; It returns exception "Target class [session] does not exist and vice versa".

But if i delete App\Classes\Translater::class from app.php's providers.

My function not working but it does not throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

With my limited knowledge, I don't think it is possible without tinkering with the help file, but I can suggest finding and replacing everything that starts with __( in your project to your custom function name instead. The double underscore function name is arbitrary anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do that by defining my translate function in the `public/index.php`
and since the method will be called after the app has been initialised you shouldn't have any issues

Inside index.php:

```php
// Overriding the default __() function to use the __translate() function
function __($text, $replace = [], $language = 'en'): string
{
// in this case i have a __translate function defined somewhere inside laravel files
    return __translate($text, $replace, $language);
}

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
// other code
```